# How to fix Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()?

Tags: excel, laravel

My program produces this error but I don't know why:

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

Code:

```
public function exportExcel(){
    $users = User::all();
    $user_array = array('Name', "Email");
    foreach($users as $user){
        $user_array[] = array(
            'Name' => $user->name,
            'Email' => $user->email,
        );

    }
    Excel::create('User Data', function ($excel) use ($user_array){
        $excel->setTitle('User Data');
        $excel->sheet('User Data', function($sheet) use ($user_array){
         $sheet->fromArray($user_array);
        });
       })->download('xls');
    return redirect()->route('admin.page');
}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel Excel you have used?

Comment: It is version 3.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this docs ([Officinal document Here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/)):

You may do this by using the make:export command.

```
php artisan make:export UsersExport --model=User
```

If you prefer to create the export manually, you can create the following in App/Exports:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

In your controller you can call this export now:

```
use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

Find your users.xlsx in your downloads folder!

Comment: which version of Excel library r u using?
u can find it in your composer.json file

Comment: 3.1.4 version is what I am using

Comment: I know this question might not stand, but can't we make excel from custom arrays. I mean to say, if they are not models. Created based on some calculations?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

you are using 
`Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel` class instead of use import facade Excel

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

other wise used

```
use Excel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the ServiceProvider in `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Add the Facade in `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
]
```

Laravel Excel can be used in a various of ways.

Usage:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
```

Comment: ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and will not be able to use in 3.0 .

Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)

Comment: When I try to use store or download it says that I am using them statically, what does this mean?